# 2023 Community Moderator Election Results

Tags: discussion, election

[Moderator election #2](https://literature.stackexchange.com/election/2) on Literature has come to a close, the votes have been tallied, and the new moderators are:

[image: Matt Thrower]

[image: Mithical]

[image: Rand al'Thor]

They will be joining [the existing crew](https://literature.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators) shortly — please thank them for volunteering and share your assistance and advice with them as they learn the ropes!

Also, please join me in thanking the following user, who will be stepping down as moderator:

[image: Tsundoku]

For details on how the voting played out, you can download the election results [here](https://literature.stackexchange.com/election/2) or [view a summary report online](https://www.opavote.com/results/5994939908358144).

Answer (score 9):

Really sorry to see Tsundoku go after all the hard work they put in to shape this site. I can only hope I can live quietly in the shadow left.

Comment: Congratulations and welcome! :-)

Answer (score 9):

Thanks to:

- Tsundoku, for 3 years of modding;
- Mithical, for 2+2 years of modding and for choosing to continue;
- Matt Thrower, for nominating and so modestly joining the team;
- Skooba and bobble, for nominating;
- all those who voted, for participating;
- you, Slate, for a lot of things not all recent;
- former mods Hamlet (2017) and Gallifreyan (2018-22), for all they did as mods;
- all of the above and many others, for everything they've contributed to this site.

Onwards!

Comment: Thanks go to you as well, Rand :) good luck to the new team!

Comment: Congrats, Rand!  You are a great mod and you will only get better! :)

Answer (score 5):

Thank you to everyone who stepped up and nominated, and to all those who voted. I appreciate your (continued) faith in me, and I'm happy for the opportunity to continue.

Tsundoku, the effort you've put into maintaining and improving the site over the past few years is very much appreciated, and I hope to see you around still even in a non-moderator capacity.

Congrats to Rand on the reelection, I don't think it comes as a surprise to anyone :)

Congrats and welcome to Matt Thrower; I'm sure you'll be an excellent addition to the team, and I look forward to working with you.

And thank you to Slate for running the election! Aside from all the effort you've put into the site in the past in different capacities, it must be a bit strange to be running the election for a site you used to moderate yourself, but the personal touch is appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

Congrats and grateful thanks to all as appropriate. And kudos to everyone who was prepared to nominate, Slightly to my shame, I cannot personally imagine having the commitment and willingness to do the drudgework that this place must require to keep going, so all of you who were willing have my utmost respect.